# Cannot import Google Storage in TypeScript

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-storage, tslint

I am trying to import Google Storage node.js module into my Firebase Cloud functions. I am using TypeScript.

```
//myfile.ts
import { Storage } from '@google-cloud/storage';

const storageInstance = new Storage({
    projectId: firebaseProjectId,
    keyFilename: "../service_accounts/" + firebaseProjectId + ".json"
});
export const bucket = storageInstance.bucket(firebaseProjectId + '.appspot.com');
```

When running `$firebase deploy`, I get:

`TypeError: storage_1.Storage is not a constructor`

Inside `/lib/myfile.js`

Answer (score 6):

The solution to this for me was

```
import * as gcs from '@google-cloud/storage';
const storage = new gcs.Storage();
const bucket = storage.bucket(bucketname);
```